# remove badge reporters when parent node has 0 child node in getorgchart

Tags: getorgchart

I'm new with getorgchart, i'm working on making an orgchart and i came across this badge reporter counter. it displays 0 when there are no reporters in your demos, what i need is that when there are no reporters, the badge should be hidden or remove.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>OrgChart | Create Your Own Theme</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
    <link href="/orgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/saveSvgAsPng.js"></script>
    <script src="/orgChart/getorgchart/svg_to_pdf.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #people {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .get-text {
            fill: #ffffff !important;
        }

        .myCustomTheme-box {
        fill: #FF8F32;
        }

        .reporters {
            fill: #0072C6;
        }

        .reporters-text {
            fill: #ffffff;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"> 
        <div id="people"></div>
    </div>
    <p><button>Download</button></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        getOrgChart.themes.myCustomTheme =
            {
                size: [500, 200],
                toolbarHeight: 46,
                textPoints: [
                    { x: 10, y: 180, width: 490 },
                    { x: 200, y: 40, width: 300 },
                    { x: 210, y: 65, width: 290 },
                    { x: 210, y: 90, width: 290 }
                ],
                textPointsNoImage: [
                    { x: 10, y: 180, width: 490 },
                    { x: 10, y: 40, width: 300 },
                    { x: 10, y: 65, width: 290 },
                    { x: 10, y: 90, width: 290 }
                ],
                expandCollapseBtnRadius: 20,
                defs: '<filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%"><feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="5" dy="5" /><feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="5" /><feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" /></filter>',
                box: '<rect x="0" y="0" height="200" width="500" rx="10" ry="10" class="myCustomTheme-box" filter="url(#f1)"  />',
                text: '<text width="[width]" class="get-text get-text-[index]" x="[x]" y="[y]">[text]</text>',
                image: '<clipPath id="getMonicaClip"><circle cx="105" cy="65" r="85" /></clipPath><image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#getMonicaClip)" xlink:href="[href]" x="20" y="-20" height="170" width="170"/>',
                reporters: '<circle cx="290" cy="230" r="20" class="reporters"></circle><text class="reporters-text" text-anchor="middle" width="120" x="290" y="237">[reporters]</text>'
         };

            var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
            var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
                theme: "myCustomTheme",
                gridView: true,
                linkType: "M",
                orientation: getOrgChart.RO_TOP,
                enableEdit: true,
                enableDetailsView: true,
                enableGridView: true,
                //enableExportToImage: true,
                renderNodeEvent: renderNodHandler,
                enablePrint: true,
                scale: 0.5,
                primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
                photoFields: ["image"],
                dataSource: [
                    { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Amber McKenzie", title: "CEO", phone: "678-772-470", mail: "lemmons@jourrapide.com", adress: "Atlanta, GA 30303", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-11.jpg" },
                    { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "Ava Field", title: "Paper goods machine setter", phone: "937-912-4971", mail: "anderson@jourrapide.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-10.jpg" },
                    { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Evie Johnson", title: "Employer relations representative", phone: "314-722-6164", mail: "thornton@armyspy.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-9.jpg" },
                    { id: 4, parentId: 1, name: "Paul Shetler", title: "Teaching assistant", phone: "330-263-6439", mail: "shetler@rhyta.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-5.jpg" },
                    { id: 5, parentId: 2, name: "Rebecca Francis", title: "Welding machine setter", phone: "408-460-0589", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-4.jpg" },
                    { id: 6, parentId: 2, name: "Rebecca Randall", title: "Optometrist", phone: "801-920-9842", mail: "JasonWGoodman@armyspy.com", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-8.jpg" },
                    { id: 7, parentId: 3, name: "Spencer May", title: "System operator", phone: "Conservation scientist", mail: "hodges@teleworm.us", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-7.jpg" },
                    { id: 8, parentId: 6, name: "Max Ford", title: "Budget manager", phone: "989-474-8325", mail: "hunter@teleworm.us", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-6.jpg" },
                    { id: 9, parentId: 7, name: "Riley Bray", title: "Structural metal fabricator", phone: "479-359-2159", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-3.jpg" },
                    { id: 10, parentId: 7, name: "Callum Whitehouse", title: "Radar controller", phone: "847-474-8775", image: "/orgChart/getorgchart/images/f-2.jpg" }
                ]
            }); 

        function renderNodHandler(sender, args) {
                for (var i = 0; i < args.content.length; i++) {
                    if (args.content[i].indexOf("[reporters]") != -1) {
                        args.content[i] = args.content[i].replace("[reporters]", args.node.children.length);
                    }
                }
        }

        document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
            svg_to_pdf(document.querySelector("svg"), function (pdf) {
                download_pdf('SVG.pdf', pdf.output('dataurlstring'));
            });
        });         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas how i can achieve it? please help. thank you

[localhost/createyourtheme_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9OLD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolve" your problem. In the function <>, you have to print <> to see the structure of the arrays, I did this:

```
console.log("ARGS");
console.log(args);
```

then, into the browser console, you have to check in which position are the elements, in my case is the position number 6, when you identify that, inside the <> you have "clean" the position, like this:

```
if(args.node.children.length==0)
{
    args.content[6] = ""
}
```

And, that's it. I "fix" the issue that way.

Comment: Thank you it works.. I just added some condition for each levels with 0 children

Also, I put these inside the for loop


 `if(args.node.children.length === 0){
                if(args.content[i].indexOf("reporters-text") != -1) {
                    args.content[i] = " "
                }
  }`